# Retrieve table column in view

Tags: php, laravel

Just started to working with laravel & I'm trying to save both item and quantity. So far, I have no idea how to retrieve item's value from table column.

Here's the code

HTML

```
  <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th class="text-center">Quantity</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody class="body">
    <tr>
      <td name="item[]">Book</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="qty[]">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td name="item[]">Pencil</td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-control" name="qty[]">
          <option value="0">0</option>
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Controller

```
$input = Input::all();

    for ($i = 0; $i < count($input['qty']); $i++) {

        $data = array(
            'item' => ?????,
            'quantity' => $input['qty'][$i]
        );

        Order::create($data);

    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

td name?? i think you must put an input inside the td and if is a form, after sending it you can retrieve the value as $_POST or $_GET depending of the method of your form